# Can you undefine a variable in Salt Pillar?

Tags: configuration, undefined, yaml, salt-stack

Given a pillar `top.sls` file like this:

```
base:
  '*': 
     - base
     - local
```

and a `base.sls` file like this:

```
mysetting: 'foo'
```

Is there anything you can put in `local.sls` which will cause `mysetting` to be undefined again?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is Probably. See the http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/pillar/#pillar-namespace-flattened for more details.

In your particular case having

```
mysetting: 'boo'
```

will definitely ***override!*** the setting.

I haven't tried it myself but I'm next to confident that the following would set the `mysseting` to undefined.

```
mysetting: None
```

Comment: Nice idea. I tested it, it doesn't work - the variable just has the value "None", so doesn't work the same as undefined in cases like Jinja's `default()` filter.

Comment: @SteveBennett Then the next closes thing what worked when tested locally is `mysetting: ''`. If your states/modules does not explicitly check for `is undefined` - then you are all settled

Comment: @SteveBennett e.g. in my local env `vagrant@fbr-enonic01:~$ sudo salt-call pillar.get mysetting
local:

` behaves the same way as for unexisting setting. And `''` still evaluates to `False` in boolean operations.

Comment: Good to know. The main place it matters is Jinja's `default` function, which specifically checks for definedness. http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/